# Load error when requiring lib directory from config/initializers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let say, that I have a `Lib` structure with directory `secret_code` inside.

```
    ├── lib
    │   ├── assets
    │   ├── files_excercises.rb
    │   ├── secret_code
    │   │   └── secret_1.rb
    │   └── tasks
```

And I want to make sure that this `lib/secret_code` is always loaded in app, therefore using initializers like this:

```
# config/initializers/secret_code.rb 
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/secret_code"
```

And I am getting this `error`:

```
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- /Users/user/project_name/lib/secret_code (LoadError)
```

What is wrong?.

Note: I am aware, that this can be done in different way, trying to understand why this approach does not work.

**EDIT**

Even if this is added into `application.rb`:

```
 config.autoload_paths  = %W(#{config.root}/lib/secret_code)
```

only `Ruby` is in `$load_path`:

```
#irb session: 
2.0.0-p353 :003 > puts $LOAD_PATH
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
config.autoload_paths  = %W(#{config.root}/lib/secret_code)
```

Comment: You might want to explain _why_ this suggestion is right, so as to make a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can require files only not directory.

If you want to require all files in secret_code you can try :

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/secret_code/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }
```